# Set ulimit when debugging with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dump

Sometimes my code crashes leaving me with an error file but no core dump because the latter is disabled.
Now it is suggested to set `ulimit -c unlimited` to allow core dumps.

If I would be running the code from console, it would be no issue to set `ulimit` before starting the Java Application. But the error seems to be much more frequent when debugged in Eclipse as when running as a standalone. (Actually as a standalone it crashed this way only once in hundreds of running hours, in debugging it crashed 4 times in the last two months (and some times before)).

Is there a way to tell Eclipse to set `ulimit` before launching a Debug-Session in Eclipse ?

And will a Core-Dump help me to find what causes the crash ?

For completeness, I am working on macOS and my error files all start like this (only `pid`changes between them):

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00007fffa08c144e, pid=617, tid=0x0000000000000307
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_181-b13) (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [AppKit+0x3a544e]  -[NSApplication _crashOnException:]+0x6d
# 
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I suspect (but have nothing to prove it except the "moment when it crashes") that the crashes are related with the handling of `BufferedImage` within the Java code, but then again, the Error-Log tells that the error happened outside the JVM.

Comment: Your Java is several years behind causing missing numerous security and other fixes, maybe also a fix for your issue: `8.0_181-b13` means Java 8 update 181, but the current Java 8 is update 312.

Comment: Ok, I've updated java now. Let's wait and see if the crashes happen again.

Comment: I was about to write that the problem was solved by updating the JDK, but right on the day I was thinking about it,  it crashed three times in a row and one time more the day after. Can try to update the JRE (which is a bit further that the JDK) and see again what happens